# Command-line tool `force-dev-tool` based on Node.js is taking lot of time before exiting

Tags: node.js, salesforce

I am using the command-line tool `force-dev-tool` which in turn uses Node.js on Linux(RHEL 7.3). When I am running the tool with the `--version` option, the command prints the version but then sort of hangs before exiting and coming back to command prompt. I am not sure what it is doing after printing the desired output. This tool is using many libraries which are also written in the Javascript. Even when I run tool with the `--help` option it prints the help information of the tool, but then again it takes a lot of time before coming back to console.

Below are some examples:

```
$> time node --version
v8.12.0

real    0m0.022s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m0.017s


$> time force-dev-tool --help

force-dev-tool.

Usage:
        force-dev-tool <command> [<args>...]
        force-dev-tool -h | --help
        force-dev-tool --version

real    0m10.503s
user    0m1.246s
sys     0m0.128s

$> time force-dev-tool --version
     2.2.2

real    0m16.427s
user    0m1.243s
sys     0m0.135s

Any help with this would be highly appreciated. Can this be related to network communication?
```

Comment: I think it makes more sense to raise your question as an issue request on the github project page. Apparently someone else already did. See https://github.com/amtrack/force-dev-tool/issues/176

Comment: Hi Marcus, Yeah i only did that and they don't have the solution to my problem(as they are not able to replicate the issue) so they have closed the issue.

Comment: I have solved the issue now it was another monitoring tool which was making the process to hang. I have uninstalled the monitoring tool agent and it works fine now.]                                                                                                                         # time force-dev-tool --version
1.1.0

real    0m0.499s
user    0m0.454s
sys     0m0.063s